# Unsolve error when declaring properties and synthesize for XMPP iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmpp, openfire

Recently I trying to develop a custom instant messaging iOS app with `XMPPframework`, I follow the tutorial according to >>> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190 and it behave as the tutorial until these errors come out. I am a beginner on developing an iOS app and using XMPP so I am suffering with how to fix these unknown errors.

I am using openfire as server, xCode version is 4.6.3, my Mac OS version is 10.7.5.

here is some code snippets

in my "JabberClientAppDelegate.h" :

`@property (nonatomic, assign) id  _chatDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id  _messageDelegate;`

and my "JabberClientAppDelegate.m" :

`@synthesize _chatDelegate;
@synthesize _messageDelegate;`

both of these properties is displaying errors that stated :

> Existing instance variable '_chatDelegate' for property
>   '_chatDelegate' with assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained
>
> Existing instance variable '_messageDelegate' for property
>   '_messageDelegate' with assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained

please guide me on how to solve these errors and I truly appreciate.

Comment: First off, remove the `_` before the variable names.  That might be throwing off the compiler since if you don't use `@synthesize _chatDelegate = somethingElse;` then it tries to create the background variable for you with a `_` prefix.

Comment: omg my life saver ! Thx for the solution it is now working fine! thank you so much!! by the way do you know the XMPP for iOS ? i just need a sample for instant messaging, once again thank you so much